# Type preference activity is dispatched

Tags: android-activity, eclipse-luna

protected    void    onCreate   (Bundle savedInstancestate)    {

super.onCreate(savedInstancestate);

addPreferencesFromResources(R.xml.prefs);

}

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: why i face this in my prog like the method addPreferencesFromResouces(int) from the type PreferenceActivity is dispatched

Answer (score 0):

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

```
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource (R.xml.YourFileName);

}
```